# specify port for standalone mode in PlayFrameWork 2.2.1

Tags: java, playframework

I have two apps developed in PlayFrameWork 2.2.1 named:
1. helloWorld_88
2. helloWorld_99

For helloWorld_88:
I want to build this app run (standalone)  on port 88.

For helloWorld_99:
I want to build this app run (standalone)  on port 99.

As I know, using "dist" task will help me to build a standalone version of apps but I don't know how to specify the port.

Can anybody advice step by step.

Thanks

> Rado
>   Hi Rado, Thanks for your quick reply.

I have already try this before I post the question, but the port always 9000.

See bellow output from the command line (Windows)

```
E:\Deploy\helloworld_88\bin>helloworld_88 -Dhttp.port=88 
Play server process ID is 2216 
[info] play - Application started (Prod) 
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

Any other idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have built both applications using "play dist" command and that you run them using generated "bin/helloWorld_88" and "bin/helloWorld_99" script files on Linux. (for Windows these files are named "bin/helloWorld_88.bat" and "bin/helloWorld_99.bat")

Go to the "bin" folder and run:

```
helloWorld_88 -Dhttp.port=88
```

and then for the second application do:

```
helloWorld_88 -Dhttp.port=99
```